# Inequality with $o$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, asymptotics

I'm trying to prove that $\ln n + \frac{1}{2n} + \gamma + o(1) < \ln(n + \frac{1}{2}) + \gamma + \frac{1}{6\cdot(2n + 1)^2}$

$o$ is small here.

I reduced the LHS to $\ln(n + \frac{1}{2}) + \ln \frac{n}{n + 1/2} + \gamma + o(1)$ and don't know how to proceed, and would like some help.

Comment: What does the $o(1)$ mean?

Comment: You can reduce the second term to o(1) as well, using e.g. Taylor series of log(1+x) for small x.

Comment: Oh it's Big O notation. Alright. I'm not sure how Big O factors into this question though?

Comment: @KSplitX It's Little o notation.  Or is it?  Perhaps the OP could clarify.

Comment: That makes more sense

Comment: Do you mean (1) that there is a function $f(n) = o(1)$ such that $\ln n + \frac{1}{2n} + \gamma + f(n) < \ln(n + \frac12) + \gamma + \frac{1}{6(2n+1)^2}$, or (2) that for all $f(n) = o(1)$, $\ln n + \frac{1}{2n} + \gamma + f(n) < \ln(n + \frac12) + \gamma + \frac{1}{6(2n+1)^2}$ holds if $n$ is sufficiently large?

Comment: @KSplitX It may not be the best article about "small o" notation, but at the bottom of the page there is some information about "small o" notation. Basically $f = o(g) \iff \forall \epsilon > 0 \ f < \epsilon g$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I was actually evaluating harmonic series and my goal is to prove that $H_n < \ln(n + \frac{1}{2}) + \gamma  + \frac{1}{6(2n + 1)^2}$. I used the Euler-Mclaurin formula and denoted $\int \limits_1^n \frac{\{t\}(1 - \{t\})}{t^3}$ as $a_n$. Then I proved that $a_n$ has a limit, let's say $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$. And then I substituted $a_n$ with $a + o(1)$. Finally $\gamma  = a  + \frac{1}{2}$. So this is where $o(1)$ comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing the error term as $o(1)$, you've given away too much information to be able to prove this inequality. For example, the inequality $$\ln n + \frac{1}{2n} + \gamma + \frac{1}{\log n} < \ln\left(n + \frac12\right) + \gamma + \frac1{6(2n+1)^2}$$ is actually false for all $n$. (In fact, just replacing that error term with $0$ gives a false statement: you need a sufficiently large negative term there for the inequality to be true.)

What you've shown to get the $o(1)$ is that $$\int_1^\infty \frac{\{t\}(1 - \{t\})}{t^3}\,\mathrm{d}t = \gamma - \frac12$$ and therefore 
$$\int_1^n \frac{\{t\}(1 - \{t\})}{t^3}\,\mathrm{d}t = \gamma - \frac12 - \epsilon_n$$ for some $\epsilon_n$, such that $\epsilon_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, that you've (validly but imprecisely) replaced by an $o(1)$. Some forensic graph-plotting suggests that to make the inequality true, you need a *lower* bound on $\epsilon_n$ on the order of $\frac{1}{12n^2}$.

Comment: (But I'm not convinced that lower-bounding $\epsilon_n$ is actually the quickest way to get to your goal. Incidentally, there's elementary methods - without any integrals whatsoever - giving the weaker estimate of $H_n < \ln (n+1) + \gamma$.)

Comment: Is $\epsilon_n > 0 \ \forall \ n$ I think it actually is, since $a_n$ is monotonically increasing...

Comment: Should be, since $\frac{\{t\}(1-\{t\})}{t^3} \ge 0$ everywhere we're integrating $t$ over.